# Python import from another file throws error

Tags: python, import

**a.py**

```
def test():
    print("hi")
```

**b.py**

```
from a import test
test('hello')
```

Error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from 'a' (C:\mypath\a.py)

**OR b.py**

```
import a
a.test('hello')
```

Error:

> AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'test'

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: I tried to run the script in another directory on my pc so it isnt because the path or something. also, os.getcwd() doesnt work*

Comment: The `test` function doesn't take any arguments. Try `test()` instead of `test("hello")`.
Also what is your folder structure?

Comment: a.test()
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'test'
`C:.
│   a.py
│   b.py
│   get_datas.py
│   pdfexctract.py
│   test.pdf
│   test1.pdf
│
├───path
└───__pycache__
        a.cpython-39.pyc
        get_datas.cpython-39.pyc`

Answer (score 0):

a.py and b.py must be in the same project forlder.

Comment: Also, if you are running the script from the Terminal, you should cd to your project forlder before runing the script.

Comment: it is: https://justpaste.it/8sj9q
also, im running from atom

Comment: check the python enviornment setup in atom. import os and print(os.getpwd()) to check that the python enterpreter is well runing from your project forlder

Comment: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'getpwd'

Comment: @TomJunges sorry use instead os.getcwd()

Comment: this works fine (but doesnt print anything or smthng)

Comment: so, what should i do now?